# Issues with layout in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Under Chrome and IE the two blocks of text are shown on the same line. However with Safari 5.1.7 the text are shown on different lines (Above and below)

I'm I missing something in css that needs to be put in place for Safari ?

HTML AND CSS is shown here http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/RKecc/

HTML

```
    <div class=" grid 6 cheese_people_l" id="cheese_people_l">
        <img id="cheese_people_l"src="img/cheese_expert.jpg">
        <p>Chief Cheese Taster <br/> Dave Le Conk</p>
        <p class="chesse_people">&ldquo;I've always had a passion for cheese. Now I get to taste it everyday! After nearly 20 years I'm still loving the job that I do. I can't actually see myself doing anything else.&rdquo;</p>
    </div>

    <div class=" grid 6 cheese_people_r" id="cheese_people_r">
        <img id="cheese_people_r" src="img/cheese_owner.jpg">
        <p>The Big Cheese Owner <br/>  Sally Fiffle</p>
        <p class="chesse_people">&ldquo;I wanted to create an online store that I'd would trust. This has been done by our amazing staff and the products they produce. Nothing can replace dedication and pasion.&rdquo;</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Safari only supports vw values from version 6+

Comment: Since the answer has to do with Safari's support of CSS3, please also include the CSS in your OP.  Do not _solely_ rely on external demo links for showing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though Safari 5 doesn't support the vw value in your widths.

It is ignoring these declarations as if there is no widths set, thus your elements have `width:100%`, and appear on different lines.

[**Reference on usage of viewport units**](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)..